# C# framework issue

Tags: c#

I just tried to get my assignment project to run but i get this error message.

```
> dotnet run

You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /home/petra/Desktop/SKOLA/PV178/hw/03/src/PV178.Homeworks.HW03/bin/Debug/net6.0/PV178.Homeworks.HW03
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet

The following frameworks were found:
  7.0.4 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64
```

From what i am understanding, there is something missing. As a c# ultranewbie, I honestly have no idea how to fix this.

```
> dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

> dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.407 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.202 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I've tried dotnet add package with the specific version, but I'm not even sure if that would resolve it (it didn't)

My computer runs Ubuntu 22.04.
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: It's odd that you have 6.0.407 as an SDK, but no 6.0 runtime. But do you *have* to target .NET 6? The *simplest* fix would be to edit your project file to target net7.0 instead of net6.0...

Comment: Did you download and install the missing framework as suggested by the error message?

Comment: "Learn about framework resolution"... "To install missing framework, download"... Read the information, click those links.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I read the information, clicked the links, tried downloading the missing framework but i'm either doing it wrong, or it didnt work

Comment: @JonSkeet Such an elegant fix! Thank you so much